# Looking for Web Series With Sound Staff

Tags: mixing, web, distribution

Hey folks. I'm trying to compile a list of videos/series that are produced exclusively for the web that actually have staff dedicated to sound. They don't necessarily have to be fictional or narrative.

Here are some examples:

- Soundworks Collection
- The recent Prometheus viral videos
- Old Spice web shorts

I'm not really looking for one-offs, I'd prefer "series" videos. If you can think of any, I'd appreciate it. *[I'd doubly appreciate it if you know the names of any sound staffers associated with them too.]*

Thanks.

**Update:**

**Thanks to everyone who responded. I was working on putting together a virtual panel discussion to talk about mixing for web. (If you haven't noticed yet, [the details were just posted to Designing Sound](http://designingsound.org/2012/06/film-sound-discussion-group-mixing-for-web/) last night). Please don't feel slighted if I didn't contact you to be on the panel. Reception for the idea was very positive, and there are limited presenter connections for the web-conferencing service. Hope to see you in the discussion.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of series that are Hulu exclusives. Definitely check them out.

Answer (score 2):

Hey matey Im the sound guy from the Corridor Digital YouTube series Sync. I basically do everything apart from the music and recording on set! What's this list for or about?

Comment: i'll send you an e-mail. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I mix a series of online videos for a large computer vendor. Don't know if that counts.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a few web series, mainly just with music and dia though, no sound design to speak of. Let me know if that's of interest..

Answer (score 2):

I've been working a documentary web series for [mashable.com](http://mashable.com/2012/05/16/vungle-ios-developer/) for the last month and a half. 
It's a 3-5 minute episodic series about a tech start up in San Francisco.

Production and post production sound handled by me. 
Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Hi Shaun,

I'm currently sound editing and mixing for the Rocket Jump/YouTube web series VGHS. So far two episodes have been released and there are another 8 episodes that will be released weekly.

Answer (score 1):

I know we talked about it the other day, adding the one I did recently. We've 2 episodes so far and after a successful Kickstarter campaign there should be more episodes come the autumn.

The Clandestine - https://vimeo.com/channels/clandestine

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for web series with good sound, or for a web series on sound, but if the former, then check out the series I worked on.
http://www.divinetheseries.com/
I was the sound designer and re-recording mixer. The series won an Indie Intertube Award for Best Sound Design.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Shaun,

I've just finished Sound Design and mix for 7 part web series Event Zero.

Episode 1 is up and can be viewed here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PatL5k6oQ74

Other episodes will be released in less than 2 weeks.

If you have any questions or need help feel free to contact me

Cheers

Sasha

Answer (score 1):

I'll be doing audio post for season 2 of JourneyQuest - www.journey-quest.com
It's a fantasy comedy.  Really funny and engaging.  I highly recommend it. And season 2 will star Fran Kranz from Dollhouse and Cabin In The Woods.

Answer (score 1):

Weve worked on a couple, heres a recent one http://www.modelminorityshow.com/